# Garage Keypad programmed to one opener now opens second opener after programming a second keypad

Tags: garage-door-opener

About a year ago I installed a new Chamberlain garage door opener on my main bay.  It has worked perfectly to date.  I have a second bay with an older Craftsman opener and recently installed a remote keypad for it as well.  It is a Chamberlain universal and after programming, it works fine.  Where my question is, and the issue I have encountered that I cannot find an answer to in the forum or elsewhere online is now my original keypad is operating both doors.  The new keypad still only opens the second bay as it should.  I have tried to reprogram the new and the original to new numbers with no luck.  Anyone have any suggestions as to how i can get one keypad to work one opener only?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You should probably contact Chamberlain on this, but my guess is both doors came with default settings which is why things are getting confused. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

You have inadvertently discovered a feature of modern rolling code garage door openers: a single remote can be programmed to operate multiple garage door openers at the same time.  It is actually a useful feature when the garage doors are at different locations (e.g., normal house and vacation house/cabin) or if you want a single remote to simultaneously operate multiple doors (e.g., an equipment shed where you always access more than one door simultaneously).

Depending on the model of the garage door opener, I am aware of two different options to remedy your situation:

1. The garage door opener may have one or more buttons that when activated will cause the garage door opener to forget all remotes that have been programmed to operate it.
2. Most garage door openers only support a small number of remotes. As you exceed the limit, the oldest remote will no longer function.  You may be able to take advantage of this limitation by reprogramming existing remotes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 2nd bay opener a Craftsman 139.5341SR. 1st bay a chamberlain WiFi model B550 which had a remote keypad that worked fine to open the 1st bay only. Used remote or wall button for the 2nd bay and recently bought a chamberlain universal remote keypad for the 2nd bay.  As soon as it was installed, the keypad for the 1st bay began operating the 2nd bay.   Tried to reset (forget) the codes in the craftsman by holding the learn button, but light never goes out, so probably an issue with the logic board. Had hoped to have each keypad operate it’s door only.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my original question.  Determined the old craftsman logic board had gone bad which didn’t allow any code resetting.  Had to replace the opener entirely which fixed my issue.